# Trigger validate on every letter typed in DevExpress TextEdit

Tags: wpf, validation, devexpress, textedit

Why does the following not trigger the [Validate](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsBaseEdit_Validatetopic) event when a letter is typed into the TextEdit? If will trigger the event only when focus is lost.

```
 <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding MyName}" ValidateOnTextInput="True" ValidateOnEnterKeyPressed="False" />
```

Comment: The default value UpdateSourceTrigger property is LostFocus,try to set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used that control, but try this:

```
<dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding MyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    ValidateOnTextInput="True" ValidateOnEnterKeyPressed="False" />
```

You can find out more from the [`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.